# Format table font/size after adding RowsBelow & exclude header

Tags: vba, ms-word

When adding rows below the header row, the subsequent rows follow the same formatting for font and font size.  I am trying to format the rows below the header row with a different font and size.

```
Sub AddRows()

With ActiveDocument
Dim myfont As Object

Set myfont = New Font
myfont.Name = "Segoe UI"
myfont.Size = 10

.Tables(2).Rows(1).Select
Selection.InsertRowsBelow (cbArraySize.Value)

''.Tables(2).Range.Font =myfont Excludeheaders:=True 'Something like 
this...

End With

End Sub
```

Expected

[image]

Actual

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's more than one way this can be done. Building on the code in the question, here's one of them.

Personally, I prefer not to work with `Selection`, but it is the only object that allows inserting multiple rows in one step. So this code gets the target table, selects it, then adds the rows.

Subsequently, the second row is assigned to a `Range` object, then the end of the range is extended to the end of the last row. Then formatting is applied to the range.

Note that in VBA, unlike, for example, the .NET languages, it's not possible to create a `Font` object and define the formatting, then assign that object to something. VBA works differently: first, the target object is required, then the properties applied to it.

What might make more sense would be to define a **style**, which can hold all the formatting settings, and apply that, rather than "manual formatting", piece-by-piece. Styles are actually the way Word was designed to be used. They're more efficient, faster and reduce memory usage.

```
Dim tbl As Word.Table
Dim rngRows As Range

Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
tbl.Select
Selection.InsertRowsBelow 3
Set rngRows = tbl.Rows(2).Range
With rngRows
    .End = tbl.Rows.Last.Range.End
    .Font.Bold = -1
    .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Size = 10
End With
```

Comment: Thank you Cindy for taking the time to explain it to me.  Worked perfectly. I can see other applications now I know how to get range to end in a table.  @Cindy Meister

Comment: Glad it helped... and will help for future tasks, @Sparks :-)